# How to modify the mean?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, estimation, mean

I have data collected in consecutive time periods using two sensors (i.e. `sensor1` and `sensor2`) as follows.

```
time      1,    2,    3,   ............,   8,    9
sensor1  0.92, 0.35, 0.18, ............, 0.36, 0.12
sensor2  0.95, 0.39, 0.09, ............, 0.18, 0.32
```

The difference of the values in the two sensors are due to environmental conditions, hardware issues etc. I want to combine these two measures of `sensor1` and `sensor2`. So, what I initailly did was taking the mean as follows.

```
time      1,    2,    3,   ............,   8,    9
sensor1  0.92, 0.35, 0.18, ............, 0.36, 0.12
sensor2  0.95, 0.39, 0.09, ............, 0.18, 0.38
mean    0.935, 0.37, 0.135, ............,0.27, 0.25
```

Considering the `mean` seems to be a good approximantion. However, I want to favour the values of `sensor2` more than `sensor1` when combining the two measures. The reason for this is that `sensor2` to is more robust to environmental changes than `sensor1`.

In that case, I am thinking of something beyond taking the `mean`. Since, my statistical knowledge is not good, I am not sure if there is any method I can use for this. My main objective is favouring `sensor2` more than `sensor1`.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the weighted mean. If you want to give sensor2 a 70% weight, you can calculate the respective weighted means via

$\text{weighted mean} = 0.7 x_{\text{sensor_2}} + 0.3 x_{\text{sensor_1}}$

Make sure the weights add up to 1!